# Centering logo in html using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is 1007px x 81px that I am using as the logo of a website and I cannot center it WITHOUT using `margin-left`. I have tried `margin: 0, auto;`

```
.navbar-brand {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 35%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you share the relevant part of your html too?

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto;` (no comma)

Comment: i forgot to include that navbar-brand has a background image. I am trying to center and image inside of it with the class navbar-brand img (if that one can be centered)

Comment: `<a class="navbar-brand hidden-s hidden-xs" href="/" style="max-width:100%"><img src="/logo_brand_md_white.png" alt="home logo"></a>  
            <a class="navbar-brand visible-s visible-xs" href="/" style="max-width:70%; margin:0px auto"><img src="/logo_brand_md_white_xs.png" alt="Home logo"></a>  
        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean center horizontally, since your element has a width, you can simply set its margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;

But setting something to width:100%; will actually take up the full size of its parent, and that means you need to center the parent, not the child.

Answer (score 0):

I've put a little snippet (at the bottom of my post) to do this. There are a few confusing things about this question as it stands.

1. I'm not sure if you intended to modify the navbar-brand class already present in bootstrap, or if you are intending to make a new class, with its own name.
2. If your image is so wide, it's probably alone on a row of your website, with nothing else beside it, which makes the layout much simpler.
3. If the below isn't what you're looking for, perhaps the issue can be more thoroughly debugged by you posting the HTML in question, a screenshot, or a fiddle of it not working as intended.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .navbar-brand {
      text-align: center;
      float: none;
      height: auto;
    }
    .navbar-brand>img {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <img width="1007" height="81" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```